# How to launch LXD container in WSL2?

Tags: lxd, wsl-2

I've set up wsl 2:

```
PS C:\Users\User> wsl --list --verbose
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-18.04    Running         2
```

However when attempting to create a container from wsl the following error is returned:

```
$ lxc launch ubuntu:18.04 test
Error: Get http://unix.socket/1.0: dial unix /var/lib/lxd/unix.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

How to launch an LXD container from wsl2? From my understanding it should be possible given that wsl2 is a full linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `sudo` before the command works.
This needs to be done for every command of lxc/lxd.